# Bootstrap Typeahead Regex -- Allowing whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap

This regex matches the search query as seen in this [example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)...

```
var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
  return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
    return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
})
```

How can I change it so that it allow whitespace at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Regex for matching all whitespace characters except the ones at the end (using lookaheads):

> ((?!\s+$)[\s])+

Or match all but the last whitespace char at the end:

> ((?!\s$)[\s])+